# PhpStorm - Wrong icon for language

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I just updated my PhpStorm to the latest version (2017.1.2) but when I open my current project (Laravel) I saw wrong icon in each file for PHP, the icon is **C** like in this picture:

[image]

But when I see for another directory, the icon is correct:

[image: But when I see for another directory, the icon is correct]

How to change the Icon to correct icon? Is it just an icon or also change the programming language to C?

Comment: Why you guys downvote my question??
I just thinking if it weird to see if the icon is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `C` is just indicating the file is entirely made up of a class matching the name of the file.

This is a recent addition to PhpStorm.

This icon has no effect on the type of file, it is still a PHP file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: In addition this is a reference to the file icons jetbrains IDE's use https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/symbols.html