# Rounded C file type in PhpStorm instead of PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm

Sorry to bother, but I searched everywhere and cant understand why my PhpStorm is showing SOME php files as c (?) file type

[image]

It highlights file in yellow, but it's a regular PHP class, same as other files in same folder.

I coudn't find exact matching icon in [icon reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html) as well.

But the main trouble is that storm doesn't commit this file, it doesn't even see it as changed.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43485173/2191572 but it does not address the commit issue.m You might need to submit a support request to them: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Ok, c icon makeks sense now. But what means yellow? And why is it excluded from visible changes? I've checked Settings/Directories - nothing special about this directory, it is not excluded.

Comment: I have no clue; I do not use PhpStorm.

Comment: **1)** `(c)` you already have an answer for that -- file has only one class inside and class name matches file name. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/symbols.html **2)** It's VCS status for that file -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-status-highlights.html

Comment: @LazyOne Could you identify which status that color applies to? Using an eyedropper on OP's screenshot leads to an inconclusive match on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-status-highlights.html. Is it the "Have changed descendants" status?

Comment: 1) He should be able to check the actual status in dedicated VCS toolwindow (sorry, I'm very new to VCS as I've used it only in 2 projects :( ) 2) Colors can be changed at `Settings/Preferences | Version Control | File Status Colors`. But visually it looks like "Ignored" or "Obsolete" status. 3) https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/01/vcs-in-depth-for-phpstorm/ A bit old, but still applicable to get the whole idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHPStorm will use a (C) icon when the *class name is identical to the file name*. If the class name differs, or if the file does not contain/contains more than a class, the PHP file icon is displayed.